# Alternative of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The Intermediate Value Theorem states that, for a continuous function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if $f(a) < d < f(b)$, then there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = d.$

I wonder if I change the hypothesis of $f(a) < d < f(b)$ to $f(a) > d > f(b)$, the result still holds. I believe so, since $f$ assumes a fixed point $f(x) = x$ in $[a,b]$, so we would have $c = d$, although I'm not completely sure.

I need this result in order to prove the set $X = \{x \in [a,b] \thinspace s.t. \thinspace f|[a,x] \thinspace \textrm {is bounded} \}$, with a continuous $f$, is not empty.

Comment: f(a) > d > f(b) = f(b) < d < f(a), so f(a) and f(b) just swap places.

Comment: The easiest way to see this is to apply your version of the theorem to $-f$ and $-d$. The condition becomes $-f(a) < -d < -f(b)$ and you can conclude that there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $-f(c)=-d$, i.e. $f(c)=d$.

Comment: @T145 I don't think that's the reason, since $a$ and $b$ are the same from the interval.

Comment: you can see that your set $X$ contain $\{a\}$

Comment: or you can use the fact that the range of a continuous function on a closed bounded interval will be bounded (i.e $f([c,d])$ is bounded $\forall c<d \in [a,b]$)

Comment: @Hamza If I put $x = a$, then I have to check that $f$ restricted to $[a,a]$, i.e. $f(a)$, is bounded, correct? How to check that? I can't see it.

Comment: your function is well defined on $a$ so $f(a)$ will be a real number so bounded

Comment: Can I use continuity to prove it? As in, from $|f(a) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, I put $\epsilon - f(x) < f(a) < f(x) + \epsilon$, then $f(a)$ would be bounded by $f(x) + \epsilon$? Is $f(x)$ bounded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46052/discussion-between-hamza-and-drhal).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're getting that $f$ has a fixed point, or how that would imply that $c=d$.  You seem to be confusing inputs and outputs of $f$: we know nothing at all about how $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are related to $a$ and $b$.

However, you can instead just apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $g(x)=-f(x)$, which satisfies $g(a)<-d<g(b)$, to get some $c$ such that $g(c)=-d$, so $f(c)=d$.

(It is not clear to me what your question has to do with proving that the set $X$ is nonempty, though.)